# Display product price in two currencies at the same time?

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

How do I modify PrestaShop 1.5 to display product prices in two currencies at the same time (ie. base currenct and visitor's currency on products listed in product & categories pages):

[image: Example]

I think I should be modifying `ProductController.php` and `product.tpl`. Is this correct?

Below is one solution for the product page that I find on a forum, but it is for PrestaShop 1.4x:

1. Override ProductController.php in /controllers/ProductController.php

   ```
   <?php
   class ProductController extends ProductControllerCore{
       public function displayContent() {
           global $currency;
           $second_currency = 'USD';
           $productPriceWithTax = Product::getPriceStatic($this->product->id, true, NULL, 6);
           if (Product::$_taxCalculationMethod == PS_TAX_INC) {
               $productPriceWithTax = Tools::ps_round($productPriceWithTax, 2);
           }
           $productPriceWithoutEcoTax = (float)($productPriceWithTax - $this->product->ecotax);

           $current_currency = $currency->iso_code;
           $default_currency = Currency::getDefaultCurrency()->iso_code;
           $currency_array   = Currency::getCurrencies($object = false, $active = 1);

           if ($current_currency == $default_currency) {
               foreach ($currency_array as $arr) {
                   if ((string)$arr['iso_code'] == $second_currency) {
                       $second_currency_price = Tools::ps_round($productPriceWithoutEcoTax * (float)$arr['conversion_rate'], 2);
                   }
               }
           }

           self::$smarty->assign('second_currency_price', $second_currency_price . ' ' . $second_currency);
           parent::displayContent();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Modify `product.tpl`:

   ```
   {if $priceDisplay >= 0 && $priceDisplay <= 2}
       <span id="our_price_display">{convertPrice price=$productPrice}</span>
   ```

   to

   ```
   {if $priceDisplay >= 0 && $priceDisplay <= 2}
       {$second_currency_price} /
       <span id="our_price_display">{convertPrice price=$productPrice}</span>
   ```

In above example USD is the second currency (`$second_currency='USD'`). I was wondering if it would be possible to modify this code for PrestaShop 1.5, which has changed significantly since 1.4x.

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop this array which contains all the currencies you manage: `{$currencies}`

```
{foreach from=$currencies item=c}{$c.name}{/foreach}
```

The default currency is in: `{$id_currency_cookie}`

If I remember, you have to write this in `product.tpl`.

I don't know how to display the correct price for your currency. Tell us if you find.

Comment: I added additional details to my question.